# Reorder Magento Onepage checkout steps

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I need one page checkout steps as

Checkout Method
Billing Information
Shipping Information
Shipping Method
Order Review
Payment Information

By default order is

Checkout Method
Billing Information
Shipping Information
Shipping Method
Payment Information
Order Review

I do not want to touch core files. I can do easily with that, but it is safe not to touch core file.

Any Idea

Many Thanks

Comment: Hi Taukil and welcome to StackOverflow. It's designed to be used by programmers for things that they are stuck on. So [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far and where exactly are you stuck? If you've not given this a go yet then do some research first and come back when you have a more specific question. This [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask a good question might also help. Hope to see you contributing again soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't modify the core files, instead just try to override the onepage checkout. To override one page checkout, you can check this link.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/34256/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/checkout/customizing_onepage_checkout_-_remove_shipping_method